# Retrieving hierarchical data from database

Tags: laravel

I have a Model (Answer) with hierarchical data like below.
[image]

I want to transfer data to array for example

```
$results=[
answer1=>answer1,
answer2=>[[answer2.1=>[answer2.1.1, answer2.1.2],answer2.2]
answer5=>answer5,
answer6=>answer6
]
```

I don't know how to do it. The problem is different number of levels in hierarchy. If level is constant I can somehow solve the problem. My code is

```
 $ar = [];
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
            $a = Answer::find($i)->toArray();
            if ($a['pid'] == NULL) {
                $ar[$a['id']] = $a;
            } else {
                $ar[$a['pid']][] = $a;
            }
        }
   return dd($ar);
```

Please give me some guidance.

Comment: maybe you could use relationships to implement this. Can you send me the csv file?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517615/retrieve-all-parent-child-records-from-database-on-laravel-hierarchical-data